# Laravel pass id to controller using AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

Route

```
Route::post('approve', 'PostsController@approve');
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.btn-approve-post').on('click', function(){
    var $btn = $(this);
    var post_id = $(this).closest('.post').data('post-id'); // it's a number like 6 or 7 or so on.

    $btn.prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'approve',
        data: {'id' : post_id},
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(response){ 
            $btn.prop('disabled', false); 
            console.log(111111);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
});
```

method in Controller

```
class PostsController extends Controller {

public function approve($id)
{
    DB::table('posts')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
}
}
```

but when I try to pass id this way, it doesn't work. How to make it work? And what type of response should give back my method in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments in the controller functions in Laravel are parameters that are in the url, defined in the routes. To get the post data, you need to use the `$request` variables.

Your code should be something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller {

    public function approve(Request $request)
    {
        DB::table('posts')
            ->where('id', $request->id)
            ->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
    }

}
```

More information about request variables can be found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: I've tried this but I got error `Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist`

Comment: You should include the following right under the namespace defenition: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are many methods to get the post parameters in the controller function as:

Method 1;

Use id as a wild card parameter in your route as

```
Route::post('approve/{id}', 'PostsController@approve');
```

In your ajax function you can get it as:

```
    $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'approve/'+post_id,
     dataType: 'json',                   
     success: function(response){ 
         $btn.prop('disabled', false); 
         console.log(111111);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
          console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
      }
   });
```

In your controller function:

```
 public function approve($id)
 {
   DB::table('posts')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
 }
```

Method 2 use request method:

In Route :

```
 Route::post('approve', 'PostsController@approve');
```

In Ajax Call:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'approve',
    data: {'id' : post_id},
    dataType: 'json',                   
    success: function(response){ 
        $btn.prop('disabled', false); 
        console.log(111111);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

In controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller {

   public function approve(Request $request)
   {
      DB::table('posts')
        ->where('id', $request->id)
        ->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use `id` as a wild card parameter in your route. So try the following Code:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller {

   public function approve(Request $request)
   {
       $id = $request->get('id');
       DB::table('posts')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but I got error `Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist`

Comment: add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` before your class. I have edited answer.